# How to play avi videos and restrict downloading it in website

Tags: php, html, video

As the title I want to play .avi video format in any browser (Preferable all browsers) and I want to restrict (make it very hard) to download or save the video.

What I did so far:

```
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<video id=v controls loop>
<source src=video.avi type=video/avi> 
<p> Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video </p>
</video>
```

JavaScript: to restrict downloading

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var v = document.getElementById('v');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 100);
    var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight / 100);
    canvas.width = cw;
    canvas.height = ch;

    v.addEventListener('play', function(){
        draw(this,context,cw,ch);
    },false);

},false);

function draw(v,c,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}
</script>
```

If my video was in mp4 format this code works great but I'm restricted not to convert them :")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very hard stuff. The YouTube is trying to do this a years.

For Dummy users is OK to block the right click and even the solution you described for mp4 files, but wen the user uses Browser Developer Tools he'll see some stuff that let him download your media.

If the video contains a copyright content, try add a watermark in the video. Even the if video was copied and published in another website, the watermark will show the real source.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution for those wishing to simply remove the right-click "save" option from the html5 videos

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
```

Comment: I already managed restricting the download sorry for updating my question late and thank you so much ^^